# Помогите с написанием интерфейса

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

У меня стоит задача сделать "**Пользовательский интерфейс**" для одного расширения.

Там нужно сделать:

- Одну кнопку добавления адреса электронной почты.
- Удаления адреса электронной почты.

Также там должны быть:

- Текстовые поля для написания в них Email адресов.
- Чтоб все добавленные Email выводились списком.

Если вы видели подобное можете скинуть ссылку или хотя бы скрин чтоб у меня было понимание как это сделать

Comment: А вы сами пытались что-то сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уроки Jquery - Html

### **Html:**

---

**input** - Предназначен для создания текстовых полей, различных кнопок, переключателей и флажков.

**button** - кнопка.

---

### Jquery

---

**click()** - Устанавливает обработчик "клика" мышью по элементу, либо, запускает это событие.

**val()** - Возвращает или устанавливает значение атрибута value.

**preventDefault()** - Действие события по умолчанию не будет выполнено.

**parent()** - Возвращает прямого родителя.

**remove()** - Удаляет все выбранные элементы из DOM (указанный элемент и всех его потомков).

**append()** - Вставляет содержимое, заданное параметром, в конец каждого элемента в наборе соответствующих элементов.

---

```js
$("#addEmail").click(function(e){ 

if($(".emailText").val() != ''){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $("ul.listEmail").append("<li>"+ $(".emailText").val() +" <span class='removeEmail'>Удалить</span></li>");
}

});

$(document).on("click",".removeEmail", function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```css
*{
  outline:none;
}
.removeEmail {
    font-size: 12px;
    vertical-align: super;
    color: #ef2b1d;
    padding-left: 5px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.removeEmail:hover {
    color: #ca0404;
}

input.emailText, #addEmail {
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #8BC34A;
    color: #4CAF50;
}
input.emailText{
  cursor:auto;
}
ul.listEmail {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
}
li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Ничего не умею помогите решить задачу. За + Вам в карму</title>
</head>
<body>     
  <p>Кнопка добавления E-mail адреса.</p>
  
  <form action="">
    <input required placeholder="Введите Email" type="email" class="emailText">

    <button id="addEmail">Добавить E-mail</button>
    <ul class="listEmail">
    </ul>
  </form>

  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: спасибо большое что не поленились и сделали)я сама помучилась сделала но ваш вариант намного лучше,ещё раз спасибо